# Perl regex email address

Tags: regex, perl, email-validation

Here is my pseudo code for my email regex:
multiple characters + one @ symbol + multiple characters + one . symbol + 2 to 6 character word

1 space must be before and after this email
you can have multiple emails per line and read entire file for emails.

So far:

```
open (MYFILE, 'data.txt');
while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @words = split(' ');
    foreach my $word (@words) {  
        if($word =~ /.+@.+\..{2,6}/) {
            print "$_\n";  
        }
    }
}
```

My problem I think is with my regex and also with my reading of the file. 
I think I am making each line a string because some results like blah@blah.com  blah are showing up so the words are not seperated?

Comment: [Regex is not the right tool for validating email addresses!](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: @Biffen `Mail::RFC822::Address`, in its geniusness, tells me that `2@2` is a valid email address. Too funny!

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack That's because it *is* a valid email address.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Email::Valid](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email%3A%3AValid).

```
use Email::Valid;
open (MYFILE, 'data.txt');
while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @words = split(' ');
    foreach my $word (@words) {  
        if(Email::Valid->address($word)) {
            print "$word\n";  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to use the regex myself and not just use a module :)

Comment: @Jason, it's bad idea

Comment: @Jason Re-using an existing implementation that follows an official spec is always preferable to rolling your own half-assed solution (it's all fun and games until some dangerous bugs or even security issues turn up). However, RFC 822 is superseded by RFC 2822 which in turn is superseded by [RFC 5332](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1). RFC 2822 is implemented by the [Email::Address](https://metacpan.org/module/Email::Address) module which should be used instead of Mail::RFC822::Address.

Comment: @amon true, for validation purposes one might want to use Email::Valid instead. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Jason then you might want to have a look at the [Regular Expressions Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596520694.do) which will explain it in much detail. But you don't want to build the regex yourself, it's far too complicated and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

I use mine:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.?[\*\+\-\_\=\^\$\#\!\~\?a-zA-Z0-9])*\.?\@([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.(?:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+))$
```

I hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Guys, what is wrong with you? Why you downvote this answer? Isn't it correct? It works perfectly and compares with 99.9% world email addresses. Can you determine why you downvoting?

Comment: Rolling your own email address validator is a bad idea, _end of story_. Either validate to the spec, or just ensure that there's an `@` sign in the field. At the end of the day, the only foolproof check is sending an actual email.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement does not print the word from the split `$word`, it prints the original line, before the split `$_`.

```
print "$_\n";
```

What you probably want is

```
print "$word\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the last part, my expression is still off though, I want the last part of the emaill address to contain only chars [A-Za-z] how do I add it in?

Comment: That was your question? Well, why not use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `.` then?

Comment: /.+@.+\..{2,6}/ is what I have but if I try /.+@.+\.[A-Za-Z]{2,6}/  nothing changes and adds with @ at the end still get matched

Comment: Did you say "adds" and mean it as an abbreviation for "addresses"? And no, that regex cannot match a string that ends with `@`.

Comment: Yes, it can match if there are multiple `@` such as in `someone@somedomain.example@`. You'll need to [anchor](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Metacharacters) your regex properly (with `^` and `$`) and then account for all the other things that can happen, such as IDNs. I highly recommend not using this regex in any production code.

Answer (score 0):

```
open (MYFILE, 'data.txt');
while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    my @words = split(' ');
    foreach my $word (@words) {
        if($word =~ /^[^@]+@+[^\.]+\.+[^\.]{2,6}$/) {
            print "$word\n";
        }
    }
}
```

First of all I want to point out that few of the valid email ids like `mine@mine.co.uk` would not fit in to your requirement. So it is always advisable to use existing working modules.

If your intention is to play around `regex` and learn like I do, then please consider the above code.

My data.txt file looks like:

```
me@me.com mine@mine.co.uk myself@email.net
me@me.com mine@mine.in myself@email.ru
me@me.com mine@mine.co.uk myself@email.america
```

Output

```
me@me.com
myself@email.net
me@me.com
mine@mine.in
myself@email.ru
me@me.com
```